# No icon on facebook share link

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, facebook-sharer

I am trying to create a share button with facebook and it works except that i got no facebook icon. Do I have to do this by myself

```
<a href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?s=100&p[title]=titlehere&p[url]=http://www.yoururlhere.com&p[summary]=yoursummaryhere&p[images][0]=http://myimage.com">link</a>
```

edit: What I am asking for is

Is it possible to get an icon from facebook or do I have to provide my own?

Comment: you have to provide your own

Answer (score 0):

You need to ensure the parameter for images points to a valid URL of an image, e.g.

```
&p[images][0]=https://www.google.co.za/images/srpr/logo4w.png
```

So the full URL would be:

```
https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?s=100&p%5Btitle%5D=titlehere&p%5Burl%5D=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.yoururlhere.com&p%5Bsummary%5D=yoursummaryhere&p%5Bimages%5D%5B0%5D=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.co.za/images/srpr/logo4w.png
```

Comment: Thank you but is it possible to get an icon from facebook or do I have to provide my own?

Comment: If the URL you are sharing has Open Graph tags properly set, then Facebook will display an image from that URL e.g. https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=www.userx.co.za

You can read more about the Open Graph protocol here: http://ogp.me/